# How to Use a Slug for a URL

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, slug

I am trying to use slugs as a way to display links on my URL. For example instead of using:

http://localhost:8000/product/1

I want to use...

http://localhost:8000/product/blue-shirts

So far I managed to add slugs via the package `cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable`. What should I use for my route and view?

```
<?php

use Sluggable;

public function sluggable()
{
    return [
        'slug' => [
            'source' => 'product_name'
        ]
    ];
}
```